# WWW/UnityWebRequest POST/GET request won't return the latest data from server/url

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get, yield, hololens

I am creating a HoloLens app using Unity which has to take data from a REST API and display it.
I am currently using WWW datatype to get the data and yield return statement in a coroutine that will be called from the Update() function. When I try to run the code, I get the latest data from the API but when someone pushes any new data onto the API, it does not automatically get the latest data in real time and I have to **restart** the app to see the latest data.
My Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class TextChange : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    WWW get;
    public static string getreq;
    Text text;
    bool continueRequest = false;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest());
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator WaitForRequest()
    {
        if (continueRequest)
            yield break;

        continueRequest = true;

        float requestFrequencyInSec = 5f; //Update after every 5 seconds 
        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(requestFrequencyInSec);

        while (continueRequest)
        {
            string url = "API Link goes Here";
            WWW get = new WWW(url);
            yield return get;
            getreq = get.text;
            //check for errors
            if (get.error == null)
            {
                string json = @getreq;
                List<MyJSC> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyJSC>>(json);
                int l = data.Count;
                text.text = "Data: " + data[l - 1].content;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Error!-> " + get.error);
            }

            yield return waitTime; //Wait for requestFrequencyInSec time
        }
    }

    void stopRequest()
    {
        continueRequest = false;
    }
}

public class MyJSC
{
    public string _id;
    public string author;
    public string content;
    public string _v;
    public string date;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling a coroutine function in the Update function like you did in your question. That's like making 60+ requests in a second.  I have addressed that in your question by replacing it with a code that waits then makes a request again. If that doesn't solve your problem then see my answer.

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Comment: Yes, and it worked like a charm....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because resources caching is enabled on the Server.

*Three possible solutions I know about*:

**1**.`Disable` resources caching on the **server**. [Instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724596/3785314) are different for every web server. Usually done in `.htaccess`.

**2**.Make each request with unique timestamp. The time should in [Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632585/3785314) format.

**This method will not work on iOS**. You are fine since this is for `HoloLens`.

For example, if your url is `http://url.com/file.rar`, append `?t=currentTime` at the end. `currentTime` is the actual time in [Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632585/3785314) Format.

Full example url: `http://url.com/file.rar?t=1468475141`

**Code**:

```
string getUTCTime()
{
    System.Int32 unixTimestamp = (System.Int32)(System.DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    return unixTimestamp.ToString();
}

private IEnumerator WaitForRequest()
{
    string url = "API Link goes Here" + "?t=" + getUTCTime();
    WWW get = new WWW(url);
    yield return get;
    getreq = get.text;
    //check for errors
    if (get.error == null)
    {
        string json = @getreq;
        List<MyJSC> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyJSC>>(json);
        int l = data.Count;
        text.text = "Data: " + data[l - 1].content;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error!-> " + get.error);
    }
}
```

**3**.`Disable` Cache on the **client** side by supplying and modifying the `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` headers in the request.

Set `Cache-Control` **header** to `max-age=0, no-cache, no-store` then set `Pragma` **header**  to `no-cache`.

I suggest you do this with `UnityWebRequest` instead of the `WWW` class. First, Include `using UnityEngine.Networking;`.

**Code**:

```
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(string url)
{

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    www.SetRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    yield return www.Send();
    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should also address the call in Update. At the moment, there are dozens of coroutine started per frame. InvokeRepeating is more appropriate.

Comment: @Everts Just noticed that and you are correct. My answer is already long and I don't want to make it longer. I have modified his answer to fix that and commented under his question to let him know about that. Note that you can't use all type of Unity `Invoke` functions with coroutines. `while` loop seems to be appropriate for this. Check the updated code in his question to see what I mean.

Comment: Make a void method that start the coroutine then you can use InvokeRepeating.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. Another reason why `while` loop is appropriate for this is that  `StartCoroutine` allocates memory each time it is called. Call it once and let it run forever. The only memory allocation now is the `WWW` class which you can't prevent. For list List, he can put it outside the while loop then re-use it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work on iOS? As long as the URL is different in a GET request or it is a POST request that might or might not have a differing request it should work.

Comment: @ChanibaL It used to work on iOS. There was an iOS version update that stopped it from working. I can't remember which one but this was years ago and there was a post about this. I can't find it anymore. Also, that method didn't work last time I tried it on iOS. Anyways, that was a heads up for the OP just in-case there is a problem with that method.