# Getting data from server and the data is not updating from server, it stays old data

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, server

I am getting data from server using `UnityWebRequest`. At the first time it receives, when I update my data in server, the unity data is not updated and it shows me old data. I have to clear the cache and again get the data from server.

Here is the code.

```
public Text mytext;

void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(GetText());
}

IEnumerator GetText() 
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://www.simplearcadegamers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/GetData.php");
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) 
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

        // Or retrieve results as binary data
        byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the PHP in this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WWW/UnityWebRequest POST/GET request won't return the latest data from server/url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365749/www-unitywebrequest-post-get-request-wont-return-the-latest-data-from-server-ur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity WWW caches results by default, as a quick workaround you can append a randomized query at the end of the URL to ensure it always returns new results, e.g. `?random=<generate random number here>` - see: https://answers.unity.com/questions/209078/disable-cache-for-www.html

A proper way to do this would be to abandon using the now obsolete WWW classes, and do proper new requests via UnityWebRequest & disabling cache.

Comment: Isn't OP using `UnityWebRequest`? It rather looks like caching is enabled server side see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38365749/7111561

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay, let me try.

Comment: @derHugo hah, you're right... I was tricked by the www variable name.

Comment: How to Save Text or Xml file to Resource Folder from server?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that :)